# Generating SQL data with CSV files Powerdesigner with 16.7

Tags: powerdesigner

It is possible to create test data for a Physical Data Model. PowerDesigner creates then for every table a CSV file with test data.

Is it possible to feed a PDM in Powerdesigner with CSV files (The other way round)?

Example:
I have folowing table

ID | name | age

Via power designer I can create test data as a csv and I would get following file.
1, Peter, 28
2, Marta, 40
3, Joe, 50

I want to do the opposite thing. I want to define a csv file for every table in my pdm and import it so that power designer creates the sql statements that insert the columns into the data base

Comment: What do you want PowerDesigner to do with the contents of those CSV files?

Comment: @pascal PowerDesigner should use the content of these csv files to fill my tables with data

Comment: @pascal I updated my question. I hope it makes it clearer

Comment: I don't think you can do it. You can define a Test Data Profile to take its value from a file, but it will be one set of values.

Comment: Maybe you can edit the DBMS to, either, define a Footer `Scripts/Sql/Objects/Table/Footer` to contain a statement like `LOAD TABLE` (for SAP SQL Anywhere) for each table; or add a Generated File on the Model `Profile/Model` containing a script to load data for each table...